# Compare performance of Process and Thread in different implementations

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I'm exploring multi-tasking in Python, after reading this [article](http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing), I create an example to compare performance between multithreading and multiprocessing:

```
dummy_data = ''.join(['0' for i in range(1048576)]) # around 1MB of data

def do_something(num):
    l = []
    for i in range(num):
        l.append(dummy_data)

def test(use_thread):
    if use_thread: title = 'Thread'
    else: title = 'Process'

    num = 1000

    jobs = []
    for i in range(4): # the test machine has 4 cores
        if use_thread:
            j = Thread(target=do_something, args=(num,))
        else:
            j = Process(target=do_something, args=(num,))
        jobs.append(j)

    start = time.time()
    for j in jobs: j.start()
    for j in jobs: j.join()
    end = time.time()
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(title, str(end - start))
```

The results are:

```
Process: 0.0416989326477
Thread: 0.149359941483
```

Which means using Process results in better performance since it utilises available cores.

However, if I change the implementation of function `do_something` to:

```
def do_something_1(num):
    l = ''.join([dummy_data for i in range(num)])
```

Using process suddenly performs worse than threading (I reduce the `num` value to 1000 due to MemoryError):

```
Process: 14.6903309822
Thread: 4.30753493309
```

Can anyone explain to me why using the second implemetation of `do_something` results in the worse performance to `Process` in compare to `Thread`?

Comment: I think it may be related to how your OS handles processes vs threads and the shared global memory. Try to move your `dummy_data` into the `do_something()` function (eliminating shared memory) and see if you get similar results. I was unable to recreate your results on Linux (RHEL6), and in fact got exact opposite results: threads were faster in your first implementation and slower in your second. Are you on Windows?